# python same string but different?

Tags: python, string, hash, error-handling, logic

I don't know why this is not working the way I want it to work. I have a text file with some common passwords(e.g. password, 00001111) and I want to hash them using a salt. However using

```
a = hashlib.sha3_256('AlwaysUseADifferentSalt00001111'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(a)
>>>6008992e30a56dbab6825064078ca585ad1b981a4c461ffb46dbd088377ac3ae

salt = 'AlwaysUseADifferentSalt'
password = '00001111'
key = salt + password
a = hashlib.sha3_256(key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(a)
>>>d6fdd92f39dd760bd372c035f76a7253b58d176b3f1e74d293218d2801d1b701
```

Gives me different results, even though `key = AlwaysUseADifferentSalt00001111`

edit:
Just to clarify some things, I am trying to reconstruct a hash with a salt and given passwords

```
import hashlib
counter = 1

sha3_pass = 'b998c2aeb78ed8948976a7c8e3317b16ba8a7ad45764520a672c684929f51f90'
sha3_file = open("Top12Thousand.txt")
salt = 'AlwaysUseADifferentSalt'

for password in sha3_file:
    key = salt + password
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha3_256(key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    #print("Trying Password %d : %s " % (counter,password.strip()))
    counter += 1

    if hash_obj == sha3_pass:
        print("\nPassword Found!!! Password Is : %s " % password)
        break
    #else:
        #print("\n password Not Found")
```

with the list from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/berzerk0/Probable-Wordlists/master/Real-Passwords/Top12Thousand-probable-v2.txt
Since I couldn't figure out why the script wasn't working I checked the salt values I get with those I would get if I inserted a whole string where I saw some differences

Comment: Works for me, my guess is you didn't run the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import hashlib
counter = 1

sha3_pass = 'b998c2aeb78ed8948976a7c8e3317b16ba8a7ad45764520a672c684929f51f90'
sha3_file = open("testfile.txt")
salt = 'AlwaysUseADifferentSalt'

for password in sha3_file:
    key = salt + password.strip()
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha3_256(key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    #print("Trying Password %d : %s " % (counter,password.strip()))
    counter += 1

    if hash_obj == sha3_pass:
        print("\nPassword Found!!! Password Is : %s " % password)
        break
    #else:
        #print("\n password Not Found")
```

As you can see the only change was stripping the password on line 9 (`key = salt + password.strip()`)

Comment: You get the same results because I'm not declaring password as a variable but rather get it from a text file. I guess that must be the reason I am having the problem but I still have no idea why it could be like that

Comment: It could help if you share a snippet of code closer to what you are running :). Like, how are you reading that file? Are you removing any newline/return chars? How is it encoded?

Comment: :) Much better, there, edited the answer. Just added `.strip()` to line 9 and it worked locally.

Comment: Great! Glad to help!